# how to run method after check box is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am building a form on an aspx page. I want to run a method that will add more fields and labels if the user ticks a checkbox labeled 'recurring donation?'

My Form

```
        <telerik:LayoutRow CssClass="formContainer">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="12" SpanSm="12" SpanMd="12">
                    <asp:Label id="firstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserFirstName"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="12" SpanSm="12" SpanMd="12">
                    <asp:Label id="lastName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserLastName"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="3" SpanSm="12" SpanMd="12">
                    <asp:Label id="address1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="userAddress1"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="9" SpanSm="12" SpanMd="12">
                    <asp:Label id="address2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="userAddress2"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="3" SpanMd="12" SpanSm="12">
                    <asp:Label ID="city" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="userCity"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="9" SpanMd="12" SpanSm="12">
                    <asp:Label ID="zip" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="userZip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                <telerik:LayoutColumn>
                    <asp:Label ID="returningDonor" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="userReturningDonor" runat="server" />
                </telerik:LayoutColumn>
            </Columns>
        </telerik:LayoutRow>
```

And my code behind

```
public partial class donationForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstName.Text = "First Name";
        lastName.Text = "Last Name";
        address1.Text = "Address 1";
        address2.Text = "Address 2";
        city.Text = "City";
        zip.Text = "Zip Code";
        returningDonor.Text = "Recurring Donation?";

        userReturningDonor.Checked = showRecuring();
    }
    static void showRecuring()
    {
        /*RUN CODE*/
    }
}
```

The error im getting is

> Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: Checked is a bollean property, showRecuring() must return a boolean value

Comment: All of the answers except mine seem to ignore the fact that you want to run some code when the checkbox becomes checked. The reason you are having problems seems to be a mix up between the `Checked` property and the `CheckedChanged` event.

Comment: @onTheInternet Do you want the page to post back and run code right when the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to try here depending on what you want to accomplish:

**Cause a post back when checkbox is clicked**

If you actually want it to post back and run code right when it's checked, I would do this:

Update your checkbox like so:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="userReturningDonor" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="userReturningDonor_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Add this to the code behind:

```
protected void userReturningDonor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (userReturningDonor.Checked) {
        MsgBox("Checked");
    } else {
        MsgBox("Not checked");
    }
}
```

**Just get rid of the error**

If you just want to get rid of the error but your code still runs as expected, then you could do this:

Change `static void showRecuring()` to `static bool showRecuring()`

`donationForm` is expecting `showRecuring` to return a `boolean` in this line:

```
userReturningDonor.Checked = showRecuring();
```

However, `showRecuring` is a `void`.

This will get rid of your error, but if you want `showRecuring` to run code based on whether or not `userReturningDonor.Checked` then you could do something like this:

**Just run function in the `Page_Load` event**

Replace `userReturningDonor.Checked = showRecuring();` with `showRecuring(userReturningDonor.Checked);`

and define `showRecuring` like so:

```
static void showRecuring(bool returningDonorChecked){
    if(returningDonorChecked) {
        //yes
    } else {
        //no
    }
}
```

Comment: @psoshmo Thanks for pointing out the poster's intend. Most of us just initially noticed what was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the return value of `showRecurring()` to the `checked` property of `userReturningDonor`, which expects a bool.

Change the return type of `showRecurring()` to a bool.

```
static bool showRecuring()
{
    /*RUN CODE*/
}
```

Comment: this answer doesnt address the fact that the OP wants to handle when the checkbox becomes checked and execute some code. he seems to have a misunderstanding of what the checked property does. Changing his method to return bool wont help him in his actual goal, it will just make the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your static method showRecuring is not returning any values (like a bool) but you are using it in the call as it should.

```
userReturningDonor.Checked = showRecuring();

static void showRecuring()
```

should be

```
static bool showRecuring()
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly edited your post instead of mine.

Comment: @TonyL. no problem. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Checked
```

is a bool that gets or set the status of the checkbox (checked or unchecked). if you want to do something when the box is checked, you want to handle the checkbox's `CheckedChanged` event. so you want something like

```
 userReturningDonor.CheckedChanged += showRecuring(usinderReturningDonor, new EventArgs());
```

and

```
 static void showRecuring(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*RUN CODE*/
}
```

EDIT: Just to be clear, the `Checked` property of the checkbox is NOT how you handle when it is checked. It is how you tell if it is currently checked or how you set it to be checked or unchecked.

EDIT 2: As other have pointed out, you are getting an error because the `Checked` property expects a true or false, where your method returns void. However, Changing your method to return a bool wont help you in your desire to run some code when a checkbox becomes checked